# Is there a function for arrays that checks if it contains another array but the order matters?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I'm stuck on an exercise where I must check if a number contains another. E.g. 1345 contains 13, or 34, but not 14. (I must not sort it also)
I wrote my code like this:

```
function numbers(p,q){
    let i = 0;
    let array_smaller = p.toString().split('');
    let array_bigger = q.toString().split('');
    let number = true
    while (i<array_smaller.length) {
        if (array_bigger.includes(array_smaller[i])){
            number = true
        }
        else {
            number = false
        }
        i++
    }
    console.log(number)
}
numbers(23,57238)
```

But includes() gives me a true value for 2,3 as 3,2, in this case.
Is there another function where the order matters? Any thoughts to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a basic [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
function numbers(p, q) {
  let testNumber = new RegExp(p);
  return testNumber.test(q);
}

console.log(numbers(23, 57238));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is about arrays, but why not do it as String? Like

```
function numbers(p,q){
  return String(q).includes(p);
};

console.log(numbers(23, 57238));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't know all the features of javascript. I started to learn how to program a few days ago. 
The point is to learn more about conditions and loops through this exercises, including applying it to the arrays. But this answer makes things a lot easier :)